# Compare lists after one is dropped

Tags: php, jquery

I working on a page in which I need to drag items from one list, drop them in a drop zone, then compare the order in which they were dropped with an answer key using a submit button. Basically a very simple drag and drop quiz. My problem is figuring out the best way to accomplish this. I know a small amount of JQuery, and PHP so any help would be appreciated.

```
<ul id="answerList">
    <li><a draggable="true" href"#" id="one">Question 1</li>
    <li><a draggable="true" href"#" id="two">Question 2</li>
    <li><a draggable="true" href"#" id="three">Question 3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="answerDrop">
    <li>Drop Answer Here</li>
</ul>

<div id="submitBtn">
     <input type="button">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: I have the drag and drop working properly, but not sure where to start to compare the list with the answer key. As for PHP I was not sure if using jquery or a combination of jquery and PHP would work for this. Is there a way to convert the dropped list into an array to compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's is your HTML:

```
<ul id="answerList">
    <li><a draggable="true" href"#" id="one">Question 1</li>
    <li><a draggable="true" href"#" id="one">Question 2</li>
    <li><a draggable="true" href"#" id="one">Question 3</li>
</ul>
```

For starters, IDs must be unique.

In your drop area:

```
<ul id="answerDrop">
    <li>Drop Answer Here</li>
</ul>
```

To view the contents on the dropped items you can use:

```
$('#answerDrop a').each(function() {
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

They will come out in the order they're shown, but you really need to grab the unique ID to tell which is which.

Comment: Sorry about the id's, forgot to change those after doing copy and paste. I will try this and see what happens.

Comment: When I tried this it will only grab the first id, nothing for the rest.

Comment: You have: $('#bin a').each(function() {
            alert($('#bin a').attr('id'));
        })

Comment: You need: $('#bin a').each(function() {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        }) ...because *$(this)* refers to the CURRENT ELEMENT IN THE LOOP.

Comment: I see what you mean and have changed the code as you suggested. How do I take this and compare it if I have an answer key such as 'var answerKey = ["four", "two", "one", "three"];'

Comment: I finally have the code to create an array using the name of the element, but it is showing the array 4 times when I console.log it. Any ideas?                               `$("#subBtn").click(function() {
var answers = []
$('#bin a').each(function() {
answers.push($(this).attr('name'));
console.log(answers);
})
}); `

Comment: You may want to post a new question with what you have so far.

Comment: Thanks, I posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200448/jquery-create-an-array-using-element-name-is-showing-multiple-times)