# jQuery create an array using element name is showing multiple times

Tags: jquery

I have this code creating an array using the element names, but instead of showing just once it shows the array 4 times. What am I doing wrong now?

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a draggable="true" href="#" id="one" name="uno" class="imgHvr">One</a></li>
    <li><a draggable="true" href="#" id="two" name="dos" class="imgHvr">2</a></li>
    <li><a draggable="true" href="#" id="three" name="tres" class="imgHvr">three</a></li>
    <li><a draggable="true" href="#" id="four" name="sweet" class="imgHvr">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$("#subBtn").click(function() {
    var answers = []
    $('#bin a').each(function() {
        answers.push($(this).attr('name'));
        console.log(answers);
    })
});
```

I have posted the complete code here [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G22ZA/2/)

Comment: That's because it's inside the `.each` loop.

Comment: Just move it outside the each loop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer form:

```
$("#subBtn").click(function() {
    var answers = []
    $('#bin a').each(function() {
        answers.push($(this).attr('name'));
    })
    console.log(answers);
});
```

Comment: Wow that was a simple fix! Thank you!!

Comment: I had this working Friday afternoon, but I came in this morning and my code is not working correctly! When I click on the #subBtn to see the array it creates, it will double everything each time you click on the button. What did I do wrong?  [Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/G22ZA/3/)

Comment: you are assigning the event handler multiple times.  Make sure the above is executed only once or use this line 1 instead:  $("#subBtn").unbind('click').click(function() {  .  This will remove  the listener before adding a new one

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it is doing the exact same thing, no change at all.

Comment: Hmm strange, does this work:  $("#subBtn").unbind().click(function() {

Comment: Same thing, not sure what is going on. The code I have worked perfect on Friday, but not now.

Comment: Try removing this code block completely.  Maybe you've pasted the event listener assignment twice?

Comment: Took your advice @user1026361 and deleted the block and retyped it. Somehow `var answers = [];` was missing in my code. Works again! Thank you!!

Comment: No I did not paste the event listener assignment twice, it was just that once piece of code missing.

Comment: lol but my original answer was correct, it was the removal of the array assignment that was the problem.  I'll be sure to keep this in mind if I see you asking for help again.